# Changing perspective of Matlab plots

Tags: matlab

Say I have a matrix `hey` 15x15. I want to plot the value of the matrix as a 2D plot for better visualization. But Matlab plots with the convention that origin is in bottom-left corner and positive x is along the left and positive y is along the up direction from origin.

but i want to make my plots such that origin is in top-left corner, +ve x is left and +ve y is down.

So i just used a slight trick.

```
figure
axis([0 15 -15 0]);
daspect([1,1,1])
hold on
rectangle('Position',[3,-6,2,3],...
          'EdgeColor','black',...
          'LineWidth',2,...
          'FaceColor','cyan')
for i=1:nrows
    for j=1:ncolumns
        if char(hey(i,j))=='^'
            text(j,-i,'^');
        elseif char(hey(i,j))=='>'
            text(j,-i,'>');
        elseif char(hey(i,j))=='v'
            text(j,-i,'v');
        elseif char(hey(i,j))=='<'
            text(j,-i,'<');
        end
        if obstacle(i,j)==1
            text(j,-i,'X');
        end
    end
end
text(goalY,-goalX,'T');
```

I made the transformation `(x,y)-->(y,-x)`. But the downside is that the axes are then numbered along y as -1 to -15. However if reader was following above, i only wanted to plot the matrix values and in matrix the y runs +ve downwards from 1 to 15 for my case.
[image]
So i want the plot to show +1 thru +15 along y with origin at top-left and x graduated as it is but the values +1 to +15 written at the top of the plot rather than below.

How to do this? In the extreme case, i am alos willing to transfer the matrix `hey` to another software that can do the nice plot as i want. If any of the two alternatives is possible, please give concrete steps to do it.

**EDIT:**
After using the helpful methods below, i still have to use a trick like `plot (j,i)` instead of the innocent `plot(i,j)`. This is because for matrix `(i,j)` is mapped to graph plot `(x,y)` as `x=j, y=i`.  Is there a similar workaround? a matrix element is (row #, column #). But in 2D matlab graph, we will denote it's position as (column #, row #). I was just guessing if there was some matlab in-built function to take care of this. like i will give it (row #, column #) but matlab will plot (column #, row #). Is there such a function?

Comment: Luis Mendo's answer below should tell you want you need. Beyond that, you should have a look at the documentation of the Matlab graphics system, in particular [Axes properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html). The graphics system is pretty versatile, many problems can be solved without resorting to tricks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I followed correctly you are looking for the axes `XAxisLocation` and `YDir` properties. You can set them to `top` and `reverse` respectively to get the output you want. You can also set the `XTick` property to `1:15` to show every value from 1 to 15.

Example:

```
clear
clc

%// Create dummy data
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

figure
quiver(x,y,u,v)


set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top','XTick',1:15,'YDir','reverse')

hold on

%// I changed the coordinated of the rectangle to fit with the change in
%y-axis.
rectangle('Position',[3,3,2,3],...
          'EdgeColor','black',...
          'LineWidth',2,...
          'FaceColor','cyan')

axis([0 15 0 15])
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

Comment: Luis's answer was simpler to understand and most likely to be chosen for implementation but your byzantine approach allows one to solve several other problems. Thanks for making the technical observation about `XAxisLocation ` and `YDir `.

Comment: I didn't initially see the "x-axis on top" requirement in the OP. I've just added that to my answer, and now I see you did it first. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @Benoit_11 Also i mentioned in my question that for matrix `(i,j)` is mapped to graph plot `(x,y)` as `x=j, y=i`. So i still have to use a trick like `plot (j,i)` instead of the innocent `plot(i,j)`. Is there a similar workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I think [`axis ij`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) does what you want:

> `axis ij` places the coordinate system origin in the upper left corner. The *i*-axis is vertical, with values increasing from top to bottom. The *j*-axis is horizontal with values increasing from left to right.

To locate the *x* axis on top, change the `'XAxisLocation'` of the axes to `'top'` (default is `'bottom'`).

Example:

```
x = 1:10;
y = x.^2;
plot(x,y)
axis ij
set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top')
```

Original plot (lines 1-3 of above code):

[image]

After `axis ij` (line 4):

[image]

After `set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top')` (line 5):

[image]

Comment: Oh nice I did not know about this command haha thanks and +1.

Comment: for the beautiful one-line solution, +1.

Comment: @Benoit_11 Actually, if you see `axis` code you'll find that `axis ij` just sets the `'YDir'` property to `'reverse'`, as you do

Comment: @LuisMendo I still have one missing link in my solution. Please see EDIT.

Comment: @giffy I don't get it. I think you can (should) use just `plot(i,j)`. Note that's what I do in my code

Comment: @LuisMendo But i was trying to plot a matirx as it is and for a matrix (i,j) corresponds to (x,y)=(j,i) in Matlab 2D plot, right? There's the issue.

Comment: @giffy I don't see why you say "for a matrix (i,j) corresponds to (x,y)=(j,i) in Matlab 2D plot". Anyway you are using `text`. First argument of `text` is x coordinate, second is y. `text` doesn't know or care where those x and y come from

Comment: @LuisMendo Yeah, so i get it. What i was trying was a matrix element is `(row #, column #)`. But in 2D matlab graph (I am assuming `axis ij` coordinate system with origin in top-left and +ve y down and +ve x right.), we will denote it's position as `(column #, row #)`. I was just guessing if there was some matlab in-built function to take care of this. like i will give it `(row #, column #)` but matlab will plot `(column #, row #)`. Is there such a function?

Comment: @giffy Maybe `view([90 90])` or `view([-90 90])`?

Comment: @LuisMendo nope, those two didn't work out but i will manage it the other way. `view([-90 -90])` seems to work though. Thanks for the idea.